# Error From Asynctask In Service Not Carrying Over To The Controller And Passed As The Api Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a nodejs API controller which routes to logic in the service of my nodejs server. The controller code is shown below:

```
  router.post('/processPayment', (req, res, next) => {
  const payload = jwtDecode(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]);
  authService.getAuthToken(payload.sub)
    .then(token => cloverPaymentService.processPayment(req.body, token.merchantId,token.cloverToken))
    .then(token => cloverPaymentService.processEncryptionV2(token.response, token.data, token.merchantId, token.cloverToken))
    .then(token => cloverPaymentService.processPaymentV2(token.response, token.data, token.merchantId, token.cloverToken))
    .then(paymentResponse => res.send(paymentResponse))
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

In my service, I have the following code that sends a post request and catches any errors:

```
const response = await got(options).catch(err=>{
    const parsedError = new HTTPError(err)
    console.error('error ' +JSON.stringify(parsedError.response.body));
    throw new Error('error: ' +parsedError.message);
  });
```

the error is caught here and printed in the console as:

```
"{\"message\":\"400 Bad Request\",\"error\":{\"type\":\"invalid_request_error\",\"code\":\"email_invalid\",\"message\":\"Please provide a valid email.\"}}"
```

Even though the error is logged and shown in the servers console, the error does not carry over to the controller and passed back to the api call. Instead I just get a standard 500 Internal Error:

```
Error: error: Response code undefined (undefined)
    at /Payment.service.js:221:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Object.processPaymentV2 (Payment.service.js:218:20)
```

I should be getting the 400 error code from running this api call not the 500 internal error and was having some trouble with this. Does anyone know how the error handling can be fixed or improved?